# Using gcc with multiple files

Tags: c, linux, shell, gcc

I am trying to generate an executable file test from a c file `test.c`.

`test.c` includes the `main()` function, but I also want to include functions from `stuff.c`. I was told to declare functions in `stuff.h` and then run the command `gcc -Wall -std=c99 stuff.c stuff.h test.c -o test`.

I know what each component of this does, but this is the first time I've tried to use gcc with multiple input files. When I try to run this command, it fails, and I get the error `clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`.

As far as I'm aware, I'm only trying to generate one output file, so I assume this command is set up incorrectly. How can I fix it?

Comment: First of all - you don't need to compile a header file.

Comment: Are you sure you are reporting the exact command line and the exact error? The `gcc` command you mentioned is expected to work.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yup this fixes it. Feel a bit silly, but thanks for the help.

Comment: BTW: you should not name your program "test". If you try to invoke it, the name "test" colides with the shell command "test". So you every have to type "./test" to get that problem away. :-)

Comment: I actually didn't expect it to fix it :)

Comment: @Arun Yeah, I provided it exactly as run.

Comment: @Klaus it has to be run that way regardless.  I doubt a test program such as this is going to be installed into the run-path anywhere.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: or you have . in PATH and the problem starts... ;)

Comment: @RothX: The problem is due to a difference in behavior between `gcc` and `clang`. Adding an answer

Comment: @Klaus is that a thing people do?  That would be more of a red flag to me than naming your test binary whatever.

Comment: @Klaus Don't worry, these are not my actual filenames. I just put placeholders for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are your errors

1. you are not suppose to compile `.h` files in c so try this:

   `gcc -Wall -std=c99 stuff.c test.c -o test`
2. `gcc` depends also on environment that you run it on. On my system if I do `gcc -Wall -std=c99 stuff.c stuff.h test.c -o test` it will work, because compiler is set that way. On some machines it might be different. So if for some strange reason #1 does not work you have to do following:

   `gcc -Wall -std=c99 -c stuff.c test.c`

   `gcc -Wall -std=c99 stuff.o test.o -o test`

   `./test`
3. But your error `clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files` is due to some code error, perhaps header file problems. So **post your code**

Answer (score 1):

The difference seems to be due to a difference of behavior between `gcc` and `clang` as shown in the following example.

```
~/test $ ls -ltr
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arusaha arusaha  0 Apr  3 13:19 b.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arusaha arusaha  0 Apr  3 13:19 b.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arusaha arusaha 14 Apr  3 13:20 a.c

~/test $ clang -Wall -std=c99 b.c b.h a.c -o ab
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files

~/test $ gcc -Wall -std=c99 b.c b.h a.c -o ab
~/test $ ls -ltr
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arusaha arusaha    0 Apr  3 13:19 b.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arusaha arusaha    0 Apr  3 13:19 b.c
-rw-rw-r-- 1 arusaha arusaha   14 Apr  3 13:20 a.c
-rwxrwxr-x 1 arusaha arusaha 8576 Apr  3 13:21 ab
~/test $
```

Compiling multiple files is supported in `gcc`, see http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_11.html

I was curious how `gcc` command can throw a `clang` error and that turned out to be a clue :). It is possible that OP's `gcc` is pointing to `clang` (and that can be confusing).

From `gcc` manpage at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html

> ```
>    -o file
>        Place output in file file.  This applies to whatever sort of
>        output is being produced, whether it be an executable file, an
>        object file, an assembler file or preprocessed C code.
>
>        If -o is not specified, the default is to put an executable file
>        in a.out, the object file for source.suffix in source.o, its
>        assembler file in source.s, a precompiled header file in
>        source.suffix.gch, and all preprocessed C source on standard
>        output.
> ```

From `clang` manpage at https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html

> ```
> -o <file> Write output to file.
> ```

To me, the difference of behavior is not exactly clear by just reading the `man` page but I could be wrong.

Comment: You should specify what the issue is in why it doesn't work (for clang) beyond the fact that clang and gcc handle it differently.

Comment: Hm, it's possible that my gcc is pointing to clang, and it would explain the error, but how would that have happened? I can't recall every intentionally doing something like that.

Comment: @RothX: You can check by running `which gcc` and `gcc --version`.